# how to use mailing system in C#

Tags: c#

i want to have an email system , when user done an action after that someone recieve an email in C#
so now how I can do that ??

Answer (score 4):

You could use the .Net *SmtpClient* class as follows:

```
using System.Net.Mail;


// the e-mail details
String from = "me@server.com";
String to   = "someone@server.com";;

// build up the message
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "My Title";
message.Body += "This is the biody of my message";

// create a server pointing to your mail server
String server = "mail.server.com";

// create a client
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

// send the message
client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

To send an email in .NET you could use the [SmptClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class.